# Is phantom voltage controlling my Lonsonho Tuya Zigbee dimmer?

Tags: lighting, dimmer-switch

I just finished installing my new Zigbee dimmer switch that also has the ability to be controlled with a press button which is powered by the power line. The idea was to connect three such buttons in parallel of which one is located near the dimmer and the other two are located rather far away (aproximately 10m). Everything seem to be working fine for the first button, but when the other two are connected to the dimmer (not pressed), it starts to behave as if the buttons were pressed constantly. Both pairs of wires to these two switches are wired under flooring and in close proximity to other wiring.

I`d very much like someone to explain to me what is happening and if there is a solution to this issue. TQ.

Comment: That item is only sold on Aliexpress, ebay, Amazon marketplace and other junk shops.  It is a dangerous and illegal piece of junk.  UL doesn't certify for reliability but it does certify for safety, and they didn't even bother applying for a UL listing, which means, you can't use it.  Back to the vendor it goes, don't let them profit off of swindling you.  In the future buy UL-listed items from reliable vendors, preferably bricks-and-mortar, as consumer safety laws DO apply to them.

Comment: I would agree with Harper but I only found 220+v version available for the  Lonsonho Tuya Zigbee dimmer so I hope there not here in the US but if in other countries you get what you pay for maybe someone that has a different experience will chime in but it looked like 5 star or 1 star so you may have gotten a lemon, try to return it.